# getenv return null from terminal while running php script

Tags: php, apache

I defined in httpd.conf(Apache) setEnv=prod 
and call to ENV in php (using getenv() function)

while running from terminal(mac) php file.php the env is NULL
but when I run it from the web page its working; and print "prod"

Comment: apache is a sapi , cli is totally different one.

Comment: Also its quite likely you have one `php.ini` for Apache and another for PHP CLI

Comment: So something you configured on the web server level has no effect when you execute your PHP script in a way that totally circumvents the web server (command line) - that should not really be a surprise.

Comment: No web server is involved when you run PHP from the Terminal application and vice-versa. They run in different environments (most probably by different users).

Comment: @axiac ohh  ,so how its can be done ? :)

Comment: How does your `getenv()` call looks like?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to set the environment of a program you run in the console (Terminal) in macOS and Linux. (The procedures are similar on Windows but the syntax is different.)

You can put `env=prod` in front of the command line to set the environment variable `env` with value `prod` only for the current execution of that command line:

```
$ env=prod php -f script.php
```

You can use `export env=prod` as a separate command line. It sets the environment value `env` with value `prod` for the current execution of the shell you are running in the console. The `export` keyword in front of it tells the shell to pass the variable to all processes it launches from now on (until you close the shell or unset the variable):

```
$ export env=prod
$ php -f script.php
```

If you want to set the variable permanently then you put the line `export env=prod` in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` or the initialization script of your preferred shell (if it's not `bash`). All subsequent instances of the shell you launch execute the initialization script and set the `env` variable with value `prod` in their environment and mark it as exportable to the child processes that shell launches.